# getting image from local storage using react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, cropperjs

I am trying to work on a simple image editor using cropperjs and react, I want my project to let the user upload an image crop it and then download it I am using the browser local storage to store the user's image then I am importing the image from local storage to the canvas, if the user does not upload an image I have a default image to let the user play with.
The local storage is storing the user image properly and download is also working for me but my problem is that the local storage image is not coming to canvas and it shows only the default image.

**here is my upload form component code**

```
import React from 'react';
const UploadForm = ({uploader}) => {
    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        uploader(e.target.files[0])
    }
    return <form>
        <input type="file" accept ="image/*" onChange ={handleChange}/>
    </form>;
}
export default UploadForm;
```

**and here is my App component code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Cropper from './comps/cropper.jsx';
import UploadForm from './comps/UploadForm.jsx';
const App = () => {
    const [url, setUrl] =useState('');
        const uploader = (file) =>{
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
            localStorage.setItem('recent-image',reader.result)
        })
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        setUrl(localStorage.getItem('recent-image'));
    }, [])
    return ( 
        <div>
            <UploadForm uploader = {uploader}/>
            <Cropper src ={url}/>
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default App;
```

**and here is my cropper component code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css';
import './cropper.css'
import image from '../image.png';
export class cropper extends Component {
    state= {
        imageDestination:""
    }
    imageElement = React.createRef();
    componentDidMount(){
        const cropper = new Cropper(this.imageElement.current, {
            // zoomable:true,
            scalable:true,
            aspectRatio:1,
            crop:()=>{
                const canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
                this.setState({
                    imageDestination:canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                })
            }

        });

    }
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
              <div className ="img-container">
                  <img ref ={this.imageElement} src ={this.props.src||image} alt ="source"/>
                  </div>  
                  <img src = {this.state.imageDestination} className = "img-preview" alt ="Destination" />
                  {this.state.imageDestination&&<a href ={this.state.imageDestination}
                   download>Download</a> 
}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default cropper
```

Answer (score 0):

in `cropper.jsx`, you `export` the class `cropper` and also `export default cropper` in the end of the file too.

`export class cropper extends Component`

`export default cropper`

Maybe that's what is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, it was a mistake but did not solve the problem.